# I need to produce a localized version of my iOS and Android apps

Tags: android, ios

I have an app that is live globally (both iOS and Android versions). I want to produce a localised version for India that has some Indian branding and slightly different colours (that's pretty much it!).

Is this possible?

How can I do it?

I would like of course to make sure that the Indian version follows the same feature updates as the global app.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which this can be approached :

1. Identify the country at app launch(I guess there are several ways to do it) and save it in the memory and create views/behaviour accordingly. Pros: This way you wont have to maintain different apps in your AppstoreConnect account. Cons: It would be too much work if your changes are minor or if you are sure you wont require the same changes for different country other than India in future.
2. Create an altogether new app and release it after restricting its country access to India on the appstore.Pros: No possible bugs from the challenges in identifying country at AppLaunch that might crop up in 1st approach.Cons: You will have to maintain different apps in AppstoreConnect account for this which is not scalable.

I would prefer 1st over 2nd as that would be scalable for different countries in the future too.

Comment: For version 1 do you mean asking the user to localise on app launch?

Comment: No, user won't get to know anything. You will just identify user's country at app launch and save it somewhere in persistent storage (e.g UserDefaults) and then access it from there and make changes to your apps views accordingly.